# image upload help needed

Tags: support, gravatar

In my Ipernity account, I was able to upload my photo directly from my PC, but here I am forced to use Gravatar, but I cannot figure out how to do it. I have selected an image (the same photo I use in Ipernity, but I am always thrown into the "Manage Gravatar" screen with no clear way of getting the image to be applied to my account here at MSE. Could someone please give me step-by-step instructions? Thanks.

Regards,
Mike Jones
27.May.2011 (Beijing time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: manage Gravatar]

You will always get thrown back to the "Manage Gravatars" screen once you upload an image. You can upload multiple ones. However, the image that's tied to your email address is always the one shown in the blue-bordered box.

Now, for your gravatar to show up on Stack Exchange sites, you need to make sure the email address associated with openID you use to log in here is the same one as the one (or one of several) you have on gravatar.com

Comment: Thanks. I got it now.